# How to fix the var(X) is now defunct

Tags: r, dplyr

I used the following function to find standard error of variables.  but when I run the same function now, it is not working.

```
st.err <- function(x) {
    sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
     }
```

I am getting an error while running this command.

> Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
>     Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
>     Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
>   Calls:  ... std.error -> unlist -> sapply -> lapply -> FUN -> var
>   Execution halted

My Rstudio is up to date, as well as all the packages I use.  Could any of you suggest an alternate function to get standard error?

Varadhu

Comment: the error message seems to mean that `x` is a factor and cannot be converted to numeric. What does `class(x)` give you?

Comment: class(x) gives me error "object(x) not found". i used this function in the following command to get aggregate. ``` aggregate(
  list(VIG=DM_data_wide$VIG,BP=DM_data_wide$BP,PROC=DM_data_wide$PROC,HYP=DM_data_wide$HYP),
  by=list(DM_data_wide$gender),FUN=st.err)```

Comment: could you insert the variable that you insert in `st.err(x)` in `class(x)` and try again?

Comment: And BTW, Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and update your question so others can help you more easily

Comment: please post a [mcve] ...

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestions.  This is my first time trying to post something in this group. i will try my best next time to post better. But, as @Lennyy  suggested,  one of my variable is a factor and removing that variable from this analysis helped in eliminating the error.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo-equivalent. (It was a very informative error message.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen recently when my data source changed. I was running source code on time series data that previously did not have a header row in the .csv file.

The new data source added a header. I removed the header and solved the error for my code. Hope this helps.